# Execute an aggregate query inside a mongo function

Tags: mongodb, function, aggregate

None of the examples show doing a simple sum inside a function, how do I do an aggregate query from a function?

Basically just trying to store a collection of known queries as a function on Mongo

Answer (score 0):

you can define your queries as functions. Assume below schema of posts in a blog that you can save it as favourite. If you need to increase or decrease`favCount` you can perform it as below,

```
const PostSchema = new Schema(
  {
    //other necessary fields as title, description of the post..etc 
    favoriteCount: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);


PostSchema.statics = {

  incFavoriteCount(postId) {
    return this.findByIdAndUpdate(postId, { $inc: { favoriteCount: 1 } });
  },

  decFavoriteCount(postId) {
    return this.findByIdAndUpdate(postId, { $inc: { favoriteCount: -1 } });
  }
};

export default mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```